# Sorting messages in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to sort:

`:messages`

in vim?

Whenever I type in `:messages` to debug some commands because it is sorted from oldest to newest and I have several hundred messages I have to press `space` about 20 times to view the most recent message. I tried `:h message` but couldn't find a place where it mentions sorting. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: [`:{count}messages`](https://vimhelp.org/message.txt.html#%3Amessages) — Show the `{count}` **most recent** messages. (Emphasize mine — *phd*).

Comment: Do `mess clear` to delete all messages before doing smth. important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually send the messages into a buffer when I need to analyse them.

```
new
put=execute('message')
```

But when I need to debug my own plugins, I use a [framework](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Log.md) (that I'm maintaining). The debug messages can be emitted either as `messages`, or as entries in the quickfix/loclist window, or into a file.